# How to Display Custom Text in ComboBox ListBox when Closed

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox

I have a ComboBox which contains a ListBox. I want to be able to set the Text on either the ComboBox or ListBox when the List is closed.

So far every effort has resulted in the Text being displayed to the Left of the ComboBox on the Outside of the Drop Down. I want the text to be set within the drop down when closed.

I have 3 items in my list. If 1 is selected (checked) I want to display the name of that item, if two, display "Multiple" and if 3 display "All". Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Initially I just want to get the text to display in the closed combo box. Changing styles has had no relevant affect.

```
<TextBlock Margin="4" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" Text="My List" Visibility="Visible">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=_ReserveStatusListBox, Path=StatusValues.Count}" Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>

                <ComboBox 
                    x:Name="_ReservesStatus"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                    Style="{StaticResource {x:Static Theme:Styles.ComboBoxSmall}}" 
                    Width="115" 
                    IsEditable="True"   
                    StaysOpenOnEdit="True">
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_ListBoxComboBoxItem" 
                                  Height="50"                                 
                                  Style="{StaticResource ListBoxComboBoxItem}">                     
                        <ListBox 
                                 x:Name="_ReserveStatusListBox"
                                 Background="{x:Null}" 
                                 BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                 Margin="0"
                                 Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=_ListBoxComboBoxItem, Mode=Default}" 
                                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                 SelectionMode="Extended"
                                 MultiSelect:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems="{Binding SelectedStatusValues}" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding StatusValues}"   
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding StatusValues[0]}"                                
                                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Local_MultiListBoxItemSelector}">                          
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>                                  
                                    <StackPanel 
                                        Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center">                             
                                        <CheckBox 
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                                            Content="{Binding}" 
                                            Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxSmall}"
                                            Foreground="Black" 
                                            FontWeight="Bold"
                                            />                                      
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>                      
                    </ComboBoxItem>                 
                    <z:EventToCommand.Bindings>
                        <z:EventBindingCollection>
                            <z:EventBinding                             
                                SourceEvent="{x:Static ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent}"
                                TargetCommand="{Binding ApplyFilterCommand}" />                         
                        </z:EventBindingCollection>
                    </z:EventToCommand.Bindings>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Could you condense your xaml down into a sample that demostrates the problem without being so verbose?  There is a lot going on here beyond the nuts and bolts of your problem.  Also, it seems very strange to me that you are using a ListBox as the the sole item of your ComboBox.

Comment: Do you want to display always the same text (defined at compiled time) or do you want to be able to change it at runtime.